# INTERMITTENT FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an android app with PeriodicWork that writes data to Firestore every 30 mins. It works fine but I noticed that in some cases, it fails with the exception `FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED`. I don't understand why it is complaining about the permission, if it can write data to Firestore.

```
// Firestore Rules
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /bar/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if true;
    }

  }
}
```

```
// Write to Firestore
val firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

firebaseFirestore.collection(BAR_KEY)
        .add(barData)
        .addOnSuccessListener { /*success callback*/ }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Crashlytics.log(e.message)
            Crashlytics.logException(e)
            /* failure callback */
        }
```

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:119)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.notifyUser(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:446)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedWrite(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:430)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.handleRejectedWrite(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:275)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWriteError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:707)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWriteStreamClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:663)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$600(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:53)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$2.onClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:206)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream.close(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:334)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream.handleServerClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:388)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onClose$3(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:149)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source:4)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:67)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:135)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.FirestoreChannel$1.onClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:161)
       at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
       at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:678)
       at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
       at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
       at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
       at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:205)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

```
Caused by io.grpc.StatusException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
       at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:534)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:117)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.notifyUser(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:446)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedWrite(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:430)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.handleRejectedWrite(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:275)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWriteError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:707)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWriteStreamClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:663)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$600(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:53)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$2.onClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:206)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream.close(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:334)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream.handleServerClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:388)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onClose$3(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:149)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source:4)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:67)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:135)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.FirestoreChannel$1.onClose(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:161)
       at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
       at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:678)
       at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
       at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
       at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
       at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.1.0:205)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Your rules allow creating data, but not updating it, which makes me think that the problem is caused by an update to an existing document. The errors you showed all start and end with Firestore's internal code. Do you have a stack trace that points to an actual line of your own code that causes the exception?

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for your reply. The exception is logged from `.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Crashlytics.log(e.message)
            Crashlytics.logException(e)
        }
`. I only want to allow a creation of data and not updating it, do I need to declare the update rule? Also, is it possible that the generated Document ID already exists and and trying to create the data caused the issue?

Comment: An `add()` should just trigger a single write as far as I know. :-/

Answer (score 0):

When you try to update the same document again it will fail.

Change add(barData) to set(barData, SetOptions.merge())

And add the below line in your security rules

```
allow update: if true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to create data not to update.

Comment: Then declare allow delete and update in rules. It will work

Comment: I want to understand the reason behind the issue. Technically, I don't want to allow delete and update. My purpose on this is some kind of a history log, so once a data is created you cannot do anything from it except for reading it.

Comment: Basically there are two rules read and write. We can define Write in three ways (Create, Update, Delete). If you want to allow only create then set create to true and update, delete to false. When you define create, then you must define rules for update and delete.